# Doubts regarding a set exercise and proof verification

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, order-theory

I took this exercise from textbook *A Course in Mathematical Analysis* by Prof D. J. H. Garling and have two questions regarding how I should infer the stimulus.

Thank you for your help!

[image]

My questions:

1. Are $A_1,A_2,A_3,...$ all ordered by the same kind of order, or every $A_i$ is ordered by a different order?
2. What is the *order* (or *orders*) that the author refers to?
3. Please check my below proof.

> For any $x,y \in A$, we have two possible cases.
>
> 1. $x=y$
>
> $\implies x \leq y$
>
> 2. $x \neq y$
>
> $\implies \exists t \in \mathbb{N}, x_t \neq y_t \implies X= \{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid x_n \neq y_n\} \neq \varnothing$.
>
> By Well-ordering Principle, $X$ has the least element and this least element is $\inf X$.
>
> $\implies k(x,y)=\inf X \in X \implies x_{k(x,y)} \neq y_{k(x,y)}$.
>
> Since $A_i$ is *TOTALLY* ordered for all $i \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x_{k(x,y)} \neq y_{k(x,y)}$, then either $x_{k(x,y)} < y_{k(x,y)}$ or $y_{k(x,y)} < x_{k(x,y)}$.
>
> If $x_{k(x,y)} < y_{k(x,y)}$, then $x \leq y$.
>
> If $y_{k(x,y)} < x_{k(x,y)}$, then $y \leq x$.
>
> To sum up, we have $x=y$ or $x \leq y$ or $y \leq x$.
>
> Thus $A$ is totally ordered by $\leq$.

Comment: Each $A_i$ comes equipped with some given total order, say $\leq_i$. And Garling defines an ordering on the product, which you are supposed to show that is a total ordering.

Comment: Hi @AsafKaragila, from your explanation, I think: when the author wrote   $x_{k(x,y} < y_{k(x,y)}$, he intended to say that the order $<$ will be different for each $A_{k(x,y)}$. It would be clearer for me if the author wrote $x_{k(x,y)} <_{k(x,y)} y_{k(x,y)}$.

Comment: Well, that's a remark to the author. :)

Comment: @AsafKaragila, I have just edited my previous comment! So my above understanding (in the previous comment) is correct?

Comment: Yes. The author was hoping that the reader would infer from the context where the comparison is taking place. Moreover, you can always assume without loss of generality that these are all subsets of a fixed linear ordering by defining a linear ordering on their [disjoint] union.

Comment: Thank you so much @AsafKaragila ^^

Comment: Hi @AsafKaragila, I have some doubts about the David's answer (the last answer) to the question at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1957650/prove-that-gcdf-m-f-n-f-gcdn-m-where-f-n-is-the-nth-fibonacci-num/1957683#comment5609219_1957683 . He rarely visits MSE. Can you please take a look at my comment on his answer?

Comment: That's really not my field, and frankly, if I had the time right now, I would have taken a closer look at this question of yours first.

Comment: I'm so grateful for all your patient help @AsafKaragila !

Comment: At the start of x /= y, you say there is a t in N such that ....  No, t needs to be the least such t.

Comment: @WilliamElliot I could not get why "$t$ needs to be the least such $t$". In my proof, I only use this $t$ to show that the set $\{n \in \mathbb{N} \mid x_n \neq y_n\} \neq \varnothing$. Please explain your thinking in a little bit more detail. Thank you so much!

Comment: Upon closer look, your proof is approvable. @DungLe

Comment: You made my day. Thank you @WilliamElliot :)